# keyframes delay between iterations

Tags: css, css-animations

Is there a way to make the **animation-delay** happen not only at the begining but also **between iterations**?

Say you have this example:

```css
.lv1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  animation: flu 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.lv2 {
  background: orange;
}
.lv3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.lv2, .lv3 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  animation: inherit;
}
@keyframes flu {
  0%, 100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50%      { transform: rotate(90deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="lv1">
  <div class="lv2">
    <div class="lv3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/GJNqMo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatly there is no property to specify delay between iterations in **infinite keyframe animations**. The [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) only specifies the time before the animation is fired the first time.

**But**

You may achieve a **delay between iterations** by modifying the keyframe animation and including the "static" time in the keyframe animation itself.

Here is an example : the div stays still for 2 seconds and rotates 90° back and forth in a 1 second timespan. The animation is infinite and each animation iteration is seprated by the 2 second pause.

```css
div {
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: flu 3s infinite;
  animation: flu 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes flu {
  66%, 100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  83%       { transform: rotate(90deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flu {
  66%, 100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  83%       { transform: rotate(90deg); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Note that you will need to addapt the percent values of the keyframe animation to fit your needs (animation duration and pause) and the animation duration.

---

Here is the same example example with a 1 second animation and a 1 second pause between iterations :

```css
div {
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: flu 2s infinite; /* <-- changed to 2s (1 second animation and 1 second pause) */
  animation: flu 2s infinite; /* <-- changed to 2s (1 second animation and 1 second pause)  */
}
@keyframes flu {
  50%, 100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }  /* changed 66% to 50% */
  75%       { transform: rotate(90deg); } /* changed 83% to 75% */
}
@-webkit-keyframes flu {
  50%, 100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }  /* changed 66% to 50% */
  75%       { transform: rotate(90deg); } /* changed 83% to 75% */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```